# Reading input throws compile error

Tags: scala, input

Pretty new to scala. I have this function:

```
  def retrieveValue(valueName:String) : Double = {
    for (ln <- io.Source.stdin.getLines) {
      val parseResult = parseValue(ln)
      parseResult match {
        case Right(x) => return x
        case Left(error) => println(error.message + " Please try again.")
      }
    }
  }
```

And I'm getting this compile error:

```
QuadSolver.scala:14: error: type mismatch;
found   : Unit
required: Double
for (ln <- io.Source.stdin.getLines) {
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parseResult match {
    case Right(x) => x  //note that `return` keyword is not needed
    case Left(error) => println(error.message + " Please try again.") //returns Unit
}
```

This piece of code return either a `Double` or a `Unit` (`Unit` provided by `println`), therefore compiler expecting a `Double` as method's return type obviously complains.

In functional programming, it's better to have each function strictly following Single-Responsibility Principle.
Thus, you should have one function aiming to retrieve the value and one to print the result.